# Lot of firebase queries cause "10 $digest() iterations reached" error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

For example, I want to make a list which looks like:

```
Apple - Steve Jobs
Microsoft - Bill Gates
Tesla - Elon Musk
```

And I'm going to do this, using two Firebase apps and AngularJS.

First FB app looks like:

```
companies
|_Apple: 0
|_Microsoft: 0
|_Tesla: 0
```

Second FB app:

```
companies-ceo
|_Apple: "Steve Jobs"
|_Microsoft: "Bill Gates"
|_Tesla: "Elon Musk"
```

So I have an AngularJs app:

```
angular.module('App', ["firebase"])
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', 
    function($scope,$firebaseObject){
        var userRef = new Firebase('https://companies.firebaseio.com/');
        var userObj = $firebaseObject(userRef);
        userObj.$bindTo($scope, "userData");

        $scope.getCEO = function(companyName){
            var indexRef = new Firebase('https://companies-ceo.firebaseio.com/'+companyName);
            var indexObj = $firebaseObject(indexRef);
            indexObj.$loaded(function(){
                return indexObj.$value;
            })
    };
```

}])

And an HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(companyName,tmp) in userData">
        <p>{{companyName}} - {{getCEO(companyName)}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I don't use getCEO() function, like:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(companyName,tmp) in userData">
        <p>{{companyName}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

everything is alright, but with getCEO() function is causes an error:

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Because you called `getCEO(companyName)` in `{{}}` directive that are getting evaluated of each digest cycle which is causing digest cycle to reach its limitation and throwing an error. Instead of doing that I'd suggest you to call `getCEO(companyName)` method on div rendering time of `ng-repeat` nothing but I'm gonna use `ng-init` here

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="(companyName,tmp) in userData" ng-init="ceo=getCEO(companyName)">
    <p>{{companyName}} - {{ceo}}</p>
</div>
```

**OR**

Another good example would be using `::` bindonce directive will run the specified method runs on only once. By using this directive `getCEO(companyName)` method will call only once.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="(companyName,tmp) in userData">
    <p>{{companyName}} - {{::getCEO(companyName)}}</p>
</div>
```

> **NOTE:-**  Bindonce `::` directive will need Angular 1.3+ version

Comment: Thank you for answer! But i still have a trouble. For clarity i'll add "console.log(indexObj.$value)" before "return indexObj.$value" row. In the first case it print "Steve Jobs" etc. but in view there are no "Steve Jobs". Just "Apple - ". And in the second case it print "Steve Jobs" etc. about 15 times (sometimes more, sometimes less) and then stop with error "[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"